# Weird variable scope in Python when using try/except

Tags: python

```
foo = 'asdf'
bar = 'asdf'
foobar = 'asdf'

def test():
  def get_foo():
    print 'foo = ' + foo

  def get_bar():
    try:
      print 'bar = ' + bar
    except Exception as e:
      print 'nobody set bar :('

  def get_foobar():
    try:
      foobar
    except Exception as e:
      print e
      foobar = "nobody set foobar :("
    print foobar

  print 'trying to get foo'
  get_foo()

  print '\ntrying to get bar'
  get_bar()

  print '\ntrying to get foobar'
  get_foobar()

test()
```

When I run this, I get this:

```
trying to get foo
foo = asdf

trying to get bar
bar = asdf

trying to get foobar
local variable 'foobar' referenced before assignment
nobody set foobar :(
```

I set up three variables: foo, bar, foobar. Then, I print them out using three nested functions: get_foo, get_bar, and get_foobar.

get_foo simply prints foo
get_bar prints bar and checks for exceptions
get_foobar uses a try-except to ensure that foobar is set before printing it.

Somehow, get_foobar fails?!

Comment: Assignment marks a variable as local.

Answer (score 2):

Add the line `global foobar` to the top of `get_foobar()`

This tells the bytecode compiler you want to reference the variable in this function using global scope instead of local.

Assignment implicitly changes a variable's scope to local for the whole function scope.

In bytecode:

```
## code input (local)
def test():
    print foobar
    foobar = 2

## bytecode output
#
# 3           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (foobar)
#             3 PRINT_ITEM 
#             4 PRINT_NEWLINE
# 
# 4           5 LOAD_CONST               1 (2)
#             8 STORE_FAST               0 (foobar)
#            11 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
#            14 RETURN_VALUE

## code input (global)
def test():
    global foobar
    print foobar
    foobar = 2

## bytecode output
#
# 4           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (foobar)
#             3 PRINT_ITEM 
#             4 PRINT_NEWLINE 
#
# 5           5 LOAD_CONST               1 (2)
#             8 STORE_GLOBAL             0 (foobar)
#            11 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
#            14 RETURN_VALUE
```

Notice the usage of `LOAD_FAST` and `STORE_FAST` instead of `LOAD_GLOBAL` and `STORE_GLOBAL`. The [Python dis module documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html#python-bytecode-instructions) has a list of opcodes for reference.

You can use this code to quickly dump the bytecode for a function:

```
import compiler, dis
code = compiler.compile('''
def test():
    print foobar
    foobar = 2
''', '__main__', 'exec')
dis.dis(code.co_consts[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Martijn Pieters called it.  Because you made an assignment to `foobar` inside the function, a new, *local* variable `foobar` was created, but this happens at compile time not runtime, which is why an uninitialized version of `foobar` is already existing inside your `try` block.